# How do I view my clipboard history on OS X?

Tags: macos, clipboard

I am often copying and pasting various tidbits of information, and then forgetting to save it. I would copy something else and lose what I had in the clipboard before.

Is there some sort of built-in way to view the history of the clipboard, or do I have to install a program?

Comment: I've tried a few 3rd-party programs, but actually found none that clears its history based *on time* rather than based on some number of entries. I don't want my Mac to remember the last xx copy actions, but want it to remember the last xx minutes. (Or, even if the number of entries is limited: at least remove the history after some time.)

Comment: @Arjan - sounds like you should write that app.

Comment: @Arjan or hire somebody on fiverr to do it.. used to be $5 might be a bit more now but not much

Comment: I recommend CopyQ as it is open source, and I like the extra power of its features eg being able to inspect the clipboard for text or html properties. Instructions on how to install via Homebrew are here:
https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/

Answer (score 89, accepted):

There's a multitude of applications that do this, but no built-in feature.

1. [Maccy](https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy)

   - Open source and free.
   - Supports searching through your clipboard history.
   - Install via: `brew install --cask maccy`
2. [Jumpcut](http://jumpcut.sourceforge.net/)

   - Open source and free.
   - Simple and straightforward.
   - Install via: `brew install --cask jumpcut`.
3. [Flycut (Mac App Store link)](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/flycut-clipboard-manager/id442160987?mt=12)

   - An open source and free fork of Jumpcut with a few added features.
   - Freely available in the Mac App Store.
   - Install via: `brew install --cask flycut`.

   [image: FlyCut, an open source fork of Jumpcut]
4. [Copy 'em Paste](http://www.apprywhere.com/copy-em-paste.html)

   - A paid, but simple and cheap alternative. Tries to do exactly one thing well.

   [image: Screenshot of Copy' em Paste on the right]
5. [Alfred Powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/)

   - Another paid alternative, with great clipboard history management as part of its pack. See [Dan Udeys answer](https://superuser.com/a/427577/137).
6. [Paste](https://pasteapp.io)

   - Another paid alternative, but requires an annual subscription.
   - Features synchronised clipboard history between Apple devices.
7. <s>[Clyppan](http://www.omh.cc/Clyppan-Clipboard-Manager-for-the-Mac/)</s>.

   Used to be open source, then closed source and available in the Mac App Store (for approx. £2), but is now no longer available for download.

Comment: This may not be a requirement for everyone, but neither Clyppan nor Jumpcut have some time-limited history. (I just opened Clyppan after not using it for some time, and it gave me my history of May 24th...)

Comment: Clyppan is now proprietary...

Comment: Flycut is awesome!

Comment: Clyppan was excellent, but is no longer under development and has some bugs in Yosemite.

Comment: Now I'm in love with this one -- http://www.apprywhere.com/copy-em-paste.html -- though I was last using Flycut, which does work nicely but it's a bit too simple. Copy 'Em Paste is insanely good, IMHO... of course, everyone has different needs, especially for this kind of util

Comment: Does Flycut support Rich Text Format content, or am I missing something? ---Oh [it doesn't](https://github.com/TermiT/Flycut/issues/12).

Comment: If you're coming here on 2022+ notice that Clipy seems to be unmaintained and not supporting images any longer. See [this thread](https://github.com/Clipy/Clipy/issues/319). I adopted one suggestion from there: [Maccy](https://github.com/p0deje/Maccy). Works great for me!

Answer (score 33):

I realise that the question has been answered, but here is another recommendation for a clipboard history manager:

[ClipMenu](http://www.clipmenu.com/)

Menubar item:

[image]

Hovering menu (hotkey):

[image]

Apart from the menubar and floating window, it also has customisable 'actions' that allow you to manipulate text as you paste it (e.g., uppercase everything), and support for snippets to hold commonly pasted text.

In my experiences it is easily the best of the simple clipboard managers.

Comment: This is a good one.

Comment: I like that this one seems to handle images, and show them inline in the history too.

Comment: Its simple and free.

Comment: I'm also a fan of ClipMenu. I have Command+Shift+V bound to bring up the menu.

Comment: Simple ? Are you kidding ?

Comment: Love it, looks like the one I used on Windows.

Comment: ClipMenu seems to have gone away? The download links all 404. :( It really is a great little utility.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7917215

Comment: Download links are dead but you can still download it from here -> https://www.dropbox.com/s/mz2v2psimbwdfql/ClipMenu.app.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 25):

The best I've found is [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/), which has a phenomenal clipboard history functionality as part of its ($15) Powerpack. Among its features:

1. Clearing history by time (e.g. 'keep only 7 days')
2. Ignore apps (so text copied from Keychain, 1password, etc. isn't saved to the history)
3. Snippets (for commonly pasted text)
4. Clipboard merging (merge the current clipboard item with the previous)
5. Max clipboard size (up to 'unlimited')

I bought it for other reasons, but I use the clipboard history every few minutes throughout my day, so for $15 it was a pretty big win.

Answer (score 21):

I was used to [ClipMenu](http://clipmenu.com), because I need a list of history items visible I don't want to waste time browsing thru history. However ClipMenu was not updated for years now, and dropbox links don't work anymore. I was able to find backed-up dmg file on one Japanese website, but what eventually solved my problem is a clone of ClipMenu called [Clipy](https://clipy-app.com/)

[image]

So you can download and install it manually or via brew cask

```
brew install --cask clipy
```

Comment: Thank you for the `brew` version, it's just amazing!

Answer (score 11):

The perennial answer to OS X questions: **[Quicksilver](http://qsapp.com/)**

[image]

See these Quicksilver clipboard tutorials:

- http://www.macinstruct.com/node/186 (recommended)
- http://theappleblog.com/2006/10/24/quicksilver-screencast-the-clipboard/
- http://blip.tv/file/1513330/

Comment: this is amazing!

Comment: +1 So hard to explain QS, impossible to live without it

Comment: Both the QS Shelf and Clipboard managers have been broken since Leopard came out.  They will open continuously and annoyingly until you shut them off.

Comment: I don't know about *Leopard*, but on *Mountain Lion* Clipboard History works without a problem.

Comment: Works on Mountain Lion for me... Copies text, links (as links), even images! 

The docking/sticking to edges does not work well at all, however, esp. in a multimon setup. Top edge would work (albeit not predictably) if I wasn't using SecondBar. For now I'm just sticking to cmd+space,L to bring it up (you can hotkey it on its own I think via triggers, just don't want to).

Comment: I find that any time I have the QS clipboard plugin enabled that almost every QS action becomes unbearably slow.

Answer (score 11):

I've tried them all and the best experience and best ongoing support has been from [**LaunchBar**](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html).

Best feature: 40-item clipboard history. It makes writing code so much easier.

[image: LaunchBar Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

I wrote [CmdVees](http://cmdvees.wuonm.com) to scratch my own itch.

It works like a **stack**. You can copy several items in sequence (like any clipboard manager) **but** when you hit Cmd-v, the pasted item is removed from the stack. LIFO. It may sounds weird, I guess it depends on how your brain works. For me is very natural.

It can be configured to work like a **queue**, FIFO, for the other brain model.

Also, it splits entries in history by time, hiding *older* items in a submenu:

[image]

To be honest I don't use the menu more than once in a while.

It has other goodies like joining items or swap top of the stack with selection.

It's a commercial app but feel free to ask me for a license if you fall in love with the trial and you can't afford it.

Comment: **A stack is not FIFO.**

Comment: This supports LIFO and FIFO

Comment: Yes, different brains work different ways. I often copy something and want to paste multiple instances of it.  Going back to the source and copying it again would be possible but tedious.  Does this software support my use case?

Comment: @Scott No, I considered it but couldn't resolve how to do it easily (just involving keyboard shortcuts).

Comment: Looks great - but website doesn't exist and other sites only offer Trial version. Good for 15 days if you're not on the US app store

Answer (score 4):

[Alfred's Powerpack](http://www.alfredapp.com/) let's you view your clipboard history for up to three months! It's not free but well worth it as it is a launcher (among other things) which is actively under development.

Answer (score 3):

[Paste](http://pasteapp.me/):clipboard history manager for your Mac

[image]

Comment: Best GUI clipboard manager by far, and the only modern option offered here (for 2016).

Answer (score 2):

[PTHPasteboard](http://pth.com/products/pthpasteboard/)

Supports at least 2,000 items in the history. (I've tried even more, though it does start to slow down at some point; a function of both the maximum number and the maximum size per entry, I expect.)

This is *extremely* handy when you're constantly jumping between a whole bunch of different systems, and those shorter histories (in other apps) just keep rotating around and losing stuff.

BTW: Another feature is that you can select to promote an item up to the top of the history, when pasting that item - keep important stuff from dropping off the bottom.

And it supports multiple pastebuffers, processing of text (such as pasting unformatted, or all upper / lower case), searching the history, etc. - lots of features.

Comment: The link gives a Peugeot 404.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a free one that allow me to view **window** from which I can drag and drop items from one long list. It's [copypaste pro](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCYQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macupdate.com%2Fapp%2Fmac%2F6856%2Fcopypaste-pro&ei=dmiEVZGEFOj_ywOBjoDABA&usg=AFQjCNEyo-v_IcUS8yWmz23ZiwAPBi9mJg&sig2=FBZ3O8BfuS4KJ09A11ogEw&bvm=bv.96339352,d.bGQ). Alfred also should do it.

Comment: Welcome to Super User.  Please see [How do I recommend software in my answers?](http://meta.superuser.com/q/5329/354511)  In particular, at a bare minimum, say where to get the software.

Answer (score 1):

BetterTouchTool (a paid tool with a free trial) now has an integrated clipboard manager / clipboard history viewer:

https://docs.folivora.ai/docs/8_clipboardmanager.html

This is a nice option if you're already using BetterTouchTool for other things, since it saves you from installing (yet?) another utility program. In addition to clipboard history, I'm currently using BetterTouchTool to:

- Map buttons 4 and 5 on my mouse (the thumb buttons) to browser forward/back
- Display the currently-playing iTunes track on my Mac's touch bar.

Answer (score 0):

Once you use [copyq](https://hluk.github.io/CopyQ/), which works on Mac, Linux and Windows you will never use anything else ... especially after you configure a global shortcut to show it ...