# Simple way to clear clipboard(copied) contents In different platforms?

Tags: windows, android, copy-paste, clipboard

I use a Win 7 machine , Android tab and Windows mobile . All these i use password wallets to keep passwords for different things . Usually i copy those password and paste in the fields . And it stays in the clipboard, if i paste it again it pastes again . If want to clear the clipboard i want do some thing as described in the article [How To Empty the Clipboard in Windows 7 [Tip]](http://www.nextofwindows.com/how-to-empty-the-clipboard-in-windows-7-tip/) in my system. In Tab and mobile its more annoying i have copy other contents to clear the current copied contents.

Is there a simple way in each of these platforms to clear clipboard ?
Installing a simple app i wouldn't mind.

Also way to clear clipboard in ios and osx wouldn't hurt? as they can see the history of clipboard: [How do I view my clipboard history on OS X?](https://superuser.com/questions/17200/how-do-i-view-my-clipboard-history-on-os-x)

Comment: A good password wallet will clear the clipboard when it closes. Did you try that? Maybe you're better off looking for wallets that do that.